# Django complaining about the username field not being unique when it is

Tags: python, django

I have a website that runs off of ajax calls that don't use JSON (because the site is so small). It first checks if the user is registered by their email, if not, they are prompted by the JS for more info before they log in. This should make sure, in a way, that the username is always unique because if not, it redirects you to a different thing. Somehow, every username I enter to test it end up with the following error `column username is not unique`

```
def log_in_pass_match(form):
    cleaned = form.cleaned_data
    if cleaned['password'] == cleaned['password2']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_is_bbn(form):
    email_bbn = form.cleaned_data['username'].split("@")
    if 'bbns.org' == email_bbn[1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_is_new_form(r):
    if "TN" in r:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_already_user(form):
    form.is_valid
    user_object = User.objects.filter(email = form.cleaned_data['username'])
    if user_object.exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def log_in_send_act(form):
    cleaned = form.cleaned_data
    msg = "To activate your account, please click the following link:<a href='"+get_random_word()+"'>Click Here</a>"
    send_mail('Activate', msg, '****@gmail.com', [cleaned['username']], fail_silently=False)
    new_user_object = User.objects.create_user(
        username=cleaned['username'],
        password=cleaned['password'],
        email=cleaned['username']
    )

def log_in_form_check(form, error):
    if form.is_valid():
        return True
    else:
        for n in form._errors:
            for e in form._errors[n]:
                error.append(e)
        return False    
def user_log_in(request):
    error = []
    form = log_in(request.POST)
    form_check = log_in_form_check(form, error)
    if form_check:
        if not log_in_already_user(form):
            form = new_user(request.POST)
            if log_in_is_new_form(request.POST):
                form_is_valid = True
                other_is_valid = True
                if form.is_valid():
                    if log_in_is_bbn(form = form) and log_in_pass_match(form = form):
                        other_is_valid = True
                    else:
                        other_is_valid = False
                else:
                    form_is_valid = False

                if form_is_valid and other_is_valid:
                    msg = "In order to activate your account at Knights of the Round Table, please click on this link:"
                    #try:
                    log_in_send_act(form = form)
                    print form.cleaned_data['username']
                    user_object = User.objects.create_user(
                        username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                        password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
                        email=form.cleaned_data['username']
                    )
                    new_user_profile = user_object.get_profile()
                    new_user_profile.pen_name = form.cleaned_data['pen_name']
                    new_user_profile.activated = False;
                    new_user_profile.save()
                    return HttpResponse("not_act")
                    #except:
                    #    error.append("Error sending email")
                else:
                    if not other_is_valid and log_in_is_new_form(request.POST):
                        if not log_in_is_bbn(form = form):
                            error.append('BBN email addresses only.')
                        if not log_in_pass_match(form = form):
                            error.append('Passwords do not match')
                    for n in form._errors:
                        for e in form._errors[n]:
                            error.append(e)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("n_usr")
        elif form_check:
            logged_in_user = auth.authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if logged_in_user is not None:
                if logged_in_user.get_profile().activated:
                    auth.login(request, logged_in_user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("")
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("not_act")
            else:
                error.append('Password Incorrect')
    errors_template = Template("{% for e in errors %}<li>{{ e }}</li> {% endfor %}")
    errors_html = errors_template.render(Context({'errors':error}))
    return HttpResponse(errors_html)
```

models.py:

```
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_info, sender=User)

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='info')
    pen_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activated = models.BooleanField()
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email + '-' + self.pen_name
```

and this is the full error:

```
    IntegrityError at /ajax/login
column username is not unique

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/login
Django Version: 1.4
Python Executable: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path: ['/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
Server time: Tue, 7 Aug 2012 22:34:35 -0400
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'Knights',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN/Knights/views.py" in user_log_in
  109.                         email=form.cleaned_data['username']
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  160.         user.save(using=self._db)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1576.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  910.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  40.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  337.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /ajax/login
Exception Value: column username is not unique
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
username = u'mgodfd@bbns.org'
TN = u'TN'
password2 = u'fff'
password = u'fff'
pen_name = u'fff'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:
csrftoken = 'Df1jB3708JUgretV8PSmRQ6NFQGI3wzL'
sessionid = 'c5eab78e2c73ff493056044d4e4362ba'

META:
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
HTTP_REFERER = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.3'
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '309'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
LOGNAME = 'Mike'
USER = 'Mike'
HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
PATH = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin'
QUERY_STRING = ''
HOME = '/Users/Mike'
wsgi.errors = <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x100284270>
TERM_PROGRAM = 'Apple_Terminal'
LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET = 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
TERM = 'xterm-256color'
SHELL = '/bin/bash'
TZ = 'America/New_York'
HTTP_COOKIE = 'csrftoken=Df1jB3708JUgretV8PSmRQ6NFQGI3wzL; sessionid=c5eab78e2c73ff493056044d4e4362ba'
SERVER_NAME = '1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
SHLVL = '1'
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
_ = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
PATH_INFO = u'/ajax/login'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '72'
TERM_SESSION_ID = '37C63610-0B15-480A-A5C3-1619ECABE279'
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH = 'XMLHttpRequest'
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/launch-elZmdg/Listeners'
wsgi.input = <socket._fileobject object at 0x101be8cd0>
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = '/tmp/launch-nMejuv/Render'
HTTP_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
SCRIPT_NAME = u''
wsgi.multithread = True
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
TMPDIR = '/var/folders/98/m4rlvgtx0d19gbmh824m8jt80000gn/T/'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
wsgi.version = 
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once = False
OLDPWD = '/Users/Mike'
wsgi.multiprocess = False
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = '0x1F5:0:0'
Apple_Ubiquity_Message = '/tmp/launch-8Ck6J2/Apple_Ubiquity_Message'
PWD = '/Users/Mike/Desktop/Main/Django-Development/BBN'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'BBN.settings'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
REMOTE_HOST = ''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip,deflate,sdch'
COMMAND_MODE = 'unix2003'

Settings:
Using settings module BBN.settings
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'BBN.urls'
MANAGERS = 
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
URL_VALIDATOR_USER_AGENT = 'Django/1.4 (https://www.djangoproject.com)'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = 
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
ADMIN_FOR = 
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = 
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'TEST_MIRROR': None, 'NAME': 'database', 'TEST_CHARSET': None, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'TEST_COLLATION': None, 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER': '', 'TEST_NAME': None, 'PASSWORD': u'********************', 'OPTIONS': {}}}
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = 
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
APPEND_SLASH = True
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES = {'default': {'LOCATION': '', 'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
'
```

Comment: The exception which is raised is not about the username not being unique but about the username=cleaned['username'] call. It seems that **cleaned** parameter is not a dict as it should be but a string, thus the error: string indices must be integers. add this: `print type(cleaned)` in the log_in_send_act function. If I'm right, it should tell you that it is a string. Then print its value so that we can have more details.

Comment: @lcfseth Well, this is unfortunate. I posted the wrong set of errors.

Comment: Have you tried to select the username to verify that Django is wrong?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The username does not exist. The database is so small at this point since I'm just testing and even when I DELETE the whole database and then use syncdb again, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It hard to tell just by looking on the code but:

```
 log_in_send_act(form = form)
 print form.cleaned_data['username']
     user_object = User.objects.create_user(
     username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
     password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
     email=form.cleaned_data['username']
 )
```

if I replace the log_in_send_act by its code, this would become:

```
 cleaned = form.cleaned_data
 msg = "To activate your account, please click the following link:<a ref='"+get_random_word()+"'>Click Here</a>"
 send_mail('Activate', msg, '****@gmail.com', [cleaned['username']], fail_silently=False)

 new_user_object = User.objects.create_user(
    username=cleaned['username'],
    password=cleaned['password'],
    email=cleaned['username']
)

print form.cleaned_data['username']
     user_object = User.objects.create_user(
     username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
     password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
     email=form.cleaned_data['username']
 )
```

With 2 successive calls to the User.create_user function with the exact same parameters. Even if data is not commited to the database, this could raise an error if Django does a Database like check on memory.

Comment: I didn't even notice that. Thanks